# Wi Fi Problem with Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.10

first of all, I am really new to Linux/Ubuntu so any kind of help/hint is gladly accepted.

Okay, so I have two problems. First one seems to be solved. It was that when I connected to Wi Fi at home, it was unstable, it was connecting and disconnecting every second. My second problem is I can't connect to school Wi Fi at all. I tried to enter without certificate (as IT of my school stated, even thought they were not much help) and with correct user name and password, it kept asking my ID and PW.

Here is what I did up to know. I played with Ubuntu a little bit to learn it but it did not end well, my Wi Fi was broken and many errors were popping. So first, I formatted the USB which had my Ubuntu install files, then I switched to Windows 10, I use dual boot, which is my main system. I copied install files of Ubuntu to USB again, and formatted Ubuntu via USB. Now that I aam home, it seems like I don't have a problem with Wi Fi but it seems weak from time to time yet I know my Wi Fi is not that good here but any kind of help to improve it is accepted.

Let me know if you need any information about my laptop, and how to check it, thank you for reading!

Edit:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
DeviceName: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11bgn 1x1 WiFi Adapter + BT 4.0 combo adapter
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

"Net" of "Network" is written in red, if it means anything.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.